# Completion and tensor product

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, formal-completions

Let $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a local ring and let $M$ be an $A$ module. If we denote with $\widehat M$ the completion of $M$ with respect the filtration:

$$\ldots\supset\mathfrak m^{i-1} M\supset\mathfrak m^{i} M\supset\mathfrak m^{i+1} M\supset\ldots$$
Is the following isomorphism true?

> $$\widehat{M}\cong M\otimes_A\widehat{A}$$

Where clearly $\widehat{A}$ is the completion of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

This is true if $A$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated (*Bourbaki*, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. 3, *Graduations, Filtrations and Topologies*, § 3, n°4, Theorem 3).

Comment: Alternate source: Q. Liu, Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, Chapter 1, section 1.3.2, Corollary 3.14 (corollary to Artin-Rees lemma)