# Finding Krull dimension of a tensor product

Tags: tensor-products, noetherian, krull-dimension

**Given:**

- A Noetherian local ring $(A,\mathfrak{m})$.
- Another Noetherian local ring $(B,\mathfrak{n})$ such that $f: A\to B$ is faithfully flat
- Residue field $k = A/\mathfrak{m} \cong B/\mathfrak{n}$.

**To prove:**

$$ \dim (B \otimes_A k) = 0$$

**My attempt:**

I know that:

- $\dim(B\otimes_B k) = 0$ since $B\otimes_B k \cong k$.
- Since $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$, each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ is contraction $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $B$.

Now, I should be able to derive some relation between $B \otimes_A k$ and $B\otimes_B k$ using this information.

This might be a dumb question, but I am just stuck here and would really appreciate some hint.

**Edit:** Source of this statement is the proof of Lemma 2.26, chapter 4 (p. 132), Q. Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves.

**Edit2:** I think the above claim holds when $B=\widehat{A}$, the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic completion of $A$. Follows from Corollary 3.14, chapter 1 (p. 21), Liu's book.

Comment: This is not true.  Are you sure you haven't omitted some hypotheses?

Comment: @EricWofsey In the actual statement, $B$ is the $I$-adic completion of $A$. Is that needed here?

Comment: Well, I can't say exactly what that would imply without knowing what $I$ is, but given that the statement is false as written, then yes, that is needed.

Comment: @EricWofsey $I$ is $\mathfrak{m}$ since $A$ is noetherian local ring as stated above.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think you were correct. If $B$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-completion of $A$ then $\widehat{A}\otimes_A k \cong \widehat{k}$ ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2545914/); bijective $A$-linear map) Hence the Krull dimension will be zero.